# Saving Excel File Based On Cell Data And Then Sending Email Using Outlook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have each of the codes to do what I said above...however I cant make them work together.

I want the code to:

First - Save excel file based on Cell C:6

Second - Draft Up An Email Automatically in Outlook

Third - But I dont want it to send automatically, I just want it to draft it open and pop up for the user.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Name = Range("C6").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Name

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)   

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "example email"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Form"
        .Body = "Test"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're really close to a solution! Here's a few things I can see.

~

Might be good to define your range in this statement:

```
Name = Range("C6").Value
```

Instead, do something like this:

```
Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("C6").Value
```

~

Next, you should define the path to your file to attach it to the email. Instead of this:

```
.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

Do this:

```
.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\Bob\...\Work_Documents\" & Name & ".xlsx"
```

~

Finally, add `.Display` inside of the `With Outmail` block (just below the `.Attachments` line) to display the email without sending it. If you ever do want it to automatically send, you can add `.Send` as well.